# Mapping an object in Hibernate that has 2 lists causing problems

Tags: java, hibernate, hbm

I'm trying to save an object that has 2 similar lists using a hbm.xml file. Below is my model object and HBM:

```
public class MyClass {

...

    private List<MyType> list;

    private List<MyType> otherList;

...

}
```

My HMB for this section is as follows:

```
    <list name="list" cascade="all-delete-orphan"
        lazy="false">
        <key column="USER_ID" />
        <list-index column="index" />
        <one-to-many class="path.to.MyType" />
    </list>

    <list name="otherList" cascade="all-delete-orphan"
        lazy="false">
        <key column="USER_ID" />
        <list-index column="index" />
        <one-to-many class="path.to.MyType" />
    </list>
```

However, when this object gets populated from the database, whatever I expect to be in 'list' is also showing up in 'otherList'. I imagine I'm missing a simple configuration change to allow hibernate to store these 2 lists properly, but I can't figure it out.

Any help?

Comment: How do you expect it to be represented in the database?

Comment: Hey there, see my comment on the answer below for more clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<list>`s contain the same content because you are telling Hibernate to map the same class (`path.to.MyType`) using the same `<key column="USER_ID">` in both instances. Are you sure you haven't made an error in the Hibernate mapping?

Conceptually, what Hibernate will do to materialize these collections is issue a query like

```
SELECT m.* from MyType m where m.USER_ID = this.USER_ID
```

If you tell Hibernate to use the same query to map both `list` and `otherList`, how can it return different results for the same query?

Comment: I see exactly what you mean, but I'm unsure as to the correct way to do it. Basically, I'm looking to store 2 separate lists of MyType for each user, hence the USER_ID being the key. This obviously works fine if there is 1 list, but I'm not sure what changes I need to make to allow 2 lists to be stored of the same type.

Comment: Well, it might be helpful to ignore Hibernate and think of how you would model this, both in the table structure and with SQL queries - what column would serve as the link to the MyType table for list1 and what column would serve as the link for list2? You may also want to read over [the chapter in the Hibernate reference manual on associations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/associations.html), which includes lots of examples of different ways to model different types of associations between classes.

Comment: MyType has a boolean column that identifies which list the row should be in (along with USER_ID). Basically what I'm looking for is the select statements to be able to say 'SELECT m.* from MyType m where m.USER_ID = this.USER_ID and m.MY_BOOLEAN = true/false' That should do the trick I would think, but again unsure how this is done in hibernate mappings.